# How to get all writable elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a function or trick how to get all writable elements from a page?

Writable elements are for example: inputs, area, etc..

If not, what can you make for me list of all writable elements?

Then, I can use `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`

No jQuery, please.

Comment: `<input type="button">` is not "writable"

Comment: Do you consider `<input type="checkbox">` to be "writable"?

Comment: Do you consider `<div>example</div><script>document.querySelector("div").contentEditable = true;</script>` to be writable?

Comment: [Some lists already exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories). With "_writable_" elements you mean _interactive_ elements?

Comment: As per what you are searching <textarea> is also an input element, so your code won't select this

Comment: Are you confusing `area` with `textarea`?

Comment: you can do a loop and pass each of the elemetn one by one to pick all the writable elements

Comment: There's [`isContentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/isContentEditable) property in elements, but the behavior seems to have been changed. In IE it returns `true` for all "writable" elements, i.e. elements you can enter text. Newer browsers seem to detect elements having `contenteditable` set to `true` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get them all easy with a single line of code, but if the HTML belongs to you and you can modify it, you can, for example add a class `writable` to all the elements you want, and then you can do:
`document.getElementsByClassName("writable");`

Comment: No, I can't, because I am not a owner of all web pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the number of inputs inside a form, you can use this:

```
formName.getElementsByTagName('input').length
```

Comment: will it work like `document.getElementsByTagName('input').length` of some one want to pick in document level not form level

Answer (score 0):

Make a function which will check all writable element like `input`, `textarea` one by one and do your operation.

Below is sample code you can use to pick writable element and do operation

```
function returnWritableEmenent() {
  var welement = ['input', 'textarea'];
  welement.map(function( ele) {
   var allele = document.getElementsByTagName(ele);
   for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     // Do something with the element here
   }
  });
}
```

You can also improve this but this is just a start. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an array and set the values to what you consider "writable" elements. Then simply loop the elements and check if their type matches an element in your list. The function then returns an array containing all the elements. Something like this:

```js
var WRITEABLE_ELEMENT_TYPES = ['text', 'textarea'];

var getWritableElements = function() {
  var writableElements = [];
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  for (let i = 0; i < forms[0].children.length; i++) {
    let element = forms[0].children[i];
    if (WRITEABLE_ELEMENT_TYPES.indexOf(element.type) > -1) {
      writableElements.push(element);
    }
  }

  return writableElements;
}

console.log(getWritableElements());
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txtField" /><br/><br/>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

Obviously you can modify this code to make it work the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a list of elements matching the selectors you choose.

For instance, if you wanted all inputs and textareas you could do the following. Note that you can specify for input element which only have certain attributes:

```js
const writableElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], textarea');
console.log(writableElements);
```

```html
<input id="i1" type="text" />
<input id="i2" type="text" />
<input id="i3" type="radio" />
<textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta3"></textarea>
```